# CORBA - JacORB: Use fixed port generating IOR?

Tags: java, corba

How do I make sure JacORB uses a fixed port, 
lets say 6001, 
when I use the ORB.object_to_string method?

I tried a few things in the JacORB config, but every generated IOR was a random port.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jacorb.net.server_socket_factory=org.jacorb.orb.factory.PortRangeServerSocketFactory

jacorb.net.server_socket_factory.port.min=52677

jacorb.net.server_socket_factory.port.max=52679

That did it for me :)

Answer (score 2):

JacORB knows the property [OAIAddr](http://www.jacorb.org/FAQ.html)

**How can I make the server use a specific port number or IP address (in case of multi-homed hosts)?**

```
JacORB provides two properties that can be set to select a port number and IP address
for servers to listen on.  These properties are OAPort and OAIAddr. Thy can be set on
the commandline using the -D switch to the Java interpreter, in the properties file, or
in the source code of the server. In this last case, they are passed as arguments to
the ORB.init() call.
```