# Determining remote port for CORBA connection

Tags: java, .net, firewall, corba

I have corba server and corba client running on different hosts and there is firewall between server and client. When client connects to server I found that several random remote ports were used on server for connection.
TCPView out:

java.exe    11816   TCPV6   xxx.domen.com   7000    xxx.domen.com   0   LISTENING
java.exe    11816   TCP xxx         7000    localhost   61392   ESTABLISHED
java.exe    11816   TCP xxx.domen.com   7000    xxx.domen.com   61393   ESTABLISHED

OpenORB(Java) is used in server and IIOP.NET is used in client.
I need to determine server range of remote ports that may be used, to meet firewall limitations.

So, the question is how can I manage/determine remote ports for server connections?

P.S.
The best way for me to meet firewall limitations is to use one bidirectional channel between client
and server with predefined ports.
P.P.S
This solution [CORBA - JacORB: Use fixed port generating IOR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726817/corba-jacorb-use-fixed-port-generating-ior)
is also appropriate, but I need solution for my orb implementations (OpenORB(Java),IIOP.NET)

Thanks for assistance =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most ORBs have an option to start your server on a fix endpoint, if you do that you can allow that port in the firewall

Answer (score 0):

> I found that several random remote ports were used on server for
>   connection

No you didn't. You only found one port in the LISTENING state. Port 7000.